# Cosa significa "buro" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Ci veniva la gente importante. Venne pure Charles Lindbérgh, quello degli aeroplani. Vita faceva tutto da sola. Era abituata a comandare. Faceva sempre di testa sua. Ce l’aveva dura. Un giorno ve la rompete, dicevo io. E issa rideva, e diceva: me la fascerò. I ganghestèr ci avevano messo la bomba, i negri ci avevano appicciato il **buro**, ne aveva passate tante, ma mai si pianse addosso.

Si sta parlando di un ristorante che Vita aveva aperto a New York negli anni trenta. Sul [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/buro) e anche su quest'[altro dizionario](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=BURO100) ho trovato che "buro" è un aggettivo che fa riferimento ai Buri, "un'antica popolazione germanica stanziata sulle rive del fiume Oder". Tuttavia, questo non sembra avere senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "buro" in questo brano? Potrebbe trattarsi di un vocabolo regionale correlato al napoletano. Può anche darsi che sia un termine italo-americano.

Comment: Beh palesemente non è italiano. Dovresti cercare in un dizionario napoletano: potrebbe significare che le avevano incendiato l'ufficio (burò)?

Comment: Penso che burò sia una storpiatura italianizzata della parola _bureau_.

Comment: @abarisone: E quindi il significato sarebbe [questo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bureau/)?

Comment: @Charo Direi che l'accezione che si adatta al contesto da te citato è la 2), ufficio.

Comment: Scusa, @OldManofAran, ma perché non sarebbe italiano?

Comment: @Charo in quella frase l'autore mischia termini italiani e dialettali (issa, appicciare), vuole persino rimarcare la pronuncia scrivendo "ganghestèr". Qui è definito "burò" un mobile con cassetti ad esempio: http://www.ilc.it/A_Mignone_Francesismi_napoletano.pdf Immagino che la grafia bureau/buro/burò sia molto variabile in ogni caso

Comment: @OldManofAran: Questo è quello che, secondo mi hanno insegnato nella Scuola Ufficiale di Lingue di Barcellona, si chiama "italiano regionale". Infatti, quando ho dato l'esame di livello C1,  gran parte degli esercizi di comprensione scritta e praticamente tutti quelli di comprensione orale (li abbiamo trovati difficilissimi) erano d'italiano regionale. Per di più, "isso", "appicciare" e "burò" (o "bureau") sono termini che si trovano sui dizionari d'italiano.

Comment: Mah, il confine è labile. Su appicciare ti do ragione, ganghestèr certo non si trova sul dizionario, mentre "isso", per quanto presente come parola arcaica, sono convinto sia percepita come parola dialettale anche da un campano (sarebbe interessante avere un parere in merito)